# How do I utilize a WHERE clause with a MONEY data type?

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause, currency, sqldatatypes

So to keep it simple, I'm working on a problem that requires a simple case of utilizing the WHERE clause to bring back records that have the field (we'll call it 'tax') equal to $0.00

So as per usual, I thought I could do:

WHERE tax = 0;

But I keep getting an error. And I'm pretty sure it's because of this weird MONEY data type. Now, just to be clear, I can't convert or change the datatype. I'm just looking for how I should be formatting that WHERE clause to make it grab those values in a data type like that. I've tried WHERE tax = 0.00, WHERE tax = $0.00, etc. etc..

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Don't use money](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_money)

Comment: Send them the link - they should know  better if they are teaching that stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the value to money:

```
where tax = 0::money
```

or cast the money type to numeric:

```
where tax::numeric = 1.23
```

or use a string value:

```
where tax = '0'
```

---

But you should really try to convert that column to a different type

Comment: So I say that I can't convert or cast or anything, cause this is a bootcamp question. They haven't taught us how to cast or convert anything. So I'm hard pressed to think that we need to do any of that. The question is literally something like "return all customers where there was zero tax." And the data type for the fixed table happens to be the money data type.

Comment: I took "*I can't convert or cast*" that you can't modify the table definition. Not that you aren't allowed to use casts

Comment: I'm saying I shouldn't have to be casting right now. And I'd rather know how to just use the WHERE clause with MONEY data types just for this simple question. I get that the data type itself is very uncommon but I still want to know what I have to use as the value after the equal sign in order to return values with tax being zero.

Comment: Thank you for your help. And I'm in the middle of sending a ticket to them with this frustrating problem. Thanks again.

Comment: @CodingNoob: don't forget to include the link to the Postgres wiki to support your claim ;)